# The \multirow command do not allow a multiple lines content inside itself

Tags: tables

I want to draw a table like
[image]

I use the `m` parameter because the rest rows of the table need it.

However if I use a `\multirow` command to combine some rows, the `m` parameter of columns will not take effect and generate a mistake.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,array}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}%a fix for array package

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}m{2cm}m{4cm}N}
\toprule[1pt]
    &\multirow{5}*{a very,\\
very long\\
text across\\
five lines\\
as above}
        &\multirow{4}*{a longer\\
        text\\
        across\\
        four lines}\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
long text in first column&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `multirow` documentation explicitly says: "If the width was given as * the text will be set in LR mode. If you want a multiline entry in this case you should use a tabular or array environment in the text parameter."  So you can't use `\\ ` in your example; or you need to set the width explicitly, which should allow the `\\ `.

Comment: @jon as you say, the `multirow` documentation tells to use `tabular` or `array` within the multirow content, if it is multiline. Thus there is no need to set the width explicitely (see my answer below)

Comment: @jfbu -- Indeed. I was trying to say that there were two solutions: use an "inner" table or set the width explicitly. I can see why the comment seems unclear now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation of `multirow` you can use `*` with multi-line contents under the condition that this multi-line content is wrapped in a tabular or an array.

This is thus what I do here. I added extra vertical space via `\ExtraSep` so that the lines are in the continuations of those of the global tabular. I used the dimensions from package `booktabs` (they are listed in the `.log` file with clear names thus I could guess their meanings).

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,array}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}%a fix for array package

\newcommand\ExtraSep
{\dimexpr\cmidrulewidth+\aboverulesep+\belowrulesep\relax}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}m{2cm}m{4cm}N}
\toprule[1pt]
    &\multirow{5}*{\begin{tabular}{l}a very,\\[\ExtraSep]
                                      very long\\[\ExtraSep]
                                      text across\\[\ExtraSep]
                                      five lines\\[\ExtraSep]
                                      as above
                \end{tabular}}
    &\multirow{4}*{\begin{tabular}{l}
                   a longer\\[\ExtraSep]
                   text\\[\ExtraSep]
                   across\\[\ExtraSep]
                   four lines\end{tabular}}\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
long text in first column&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with multirow]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use line breaks inside `\multirow` you have to specify a fixed width. Note also that `\multirow` doesn't produce the desired result in such cases, unless you make some manual adjustments, as in the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,array}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}%a fix for array package

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}m{2cm}m{4cm}N}
\toprule[1pt]
    &\multirow{5}{2cm}{a very,\\[.4\baselineskip]
    very long\\[.4\baselineskip]
    text across\\[.4\baselineskip]
    five lines\\[.4\baselineskip]
    as above}
        &\multirow{5}[8]{4cm}{a longer\\[.4\baselineskip]
        text\\[.4\baselineskip]
        across\\[.4\baselineskip]
        four lines}\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
long text in first column&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you are using

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
```

the following adjustments are needed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,array}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}%a fix for array package

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}m{2cm}m{4cm}N}
\toprule[1pt]
    &\multirow{5}{2cm}[.5ex]{a very,\\[.1ex]
    very long\\[.1ex]
    text across\\[.1ex]
    five lines\\[.1ex]
    as above}
        &\multirow{5}{4cm}[-1ex]{a longer\\[.1ex]
        text\\[.1ex]
        across\\[.1ex]
        four lines}\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
long text in first column&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\cmidrule{1-1}
&&\\\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You must be a kind guy. Thank you. Do you mind tell me, how to calculate the `.4\baselineskip`? If I change the `\arraystretch` to 0.5, the `.4\baselineskip` are obliged to change with?

Comment: @pgffans by attempts... I've added the adjustments needed with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}` in the edit.

Comment: @pgffans Notice that, apart from accepting answers, you're also allowed to upvote them, if you find them useful.

Comment: I have left click the "up" pattern by mouse several times, and it seems unresponsive. Could you answer this questions when you are free? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233748/how-to-use-the-widthof-in-a-multirow-command-as-its-second-parament

Comment: @SignupforAhWoo Probably you are not able to upvote because you're not a registered user. Please register yourself here.