# How to use \widthof in a \multirow command as its second parameter

Tags: multirow

Why I can not use the `\widthof` in a `\multirow` command as its second argument? The code below run wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,calc,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{rcl}
lemma 1&\multirow{3}{\widthof{$\iff$}}{$\iff$}&theorem 1\\
lemma 2&                                      &theorem 2\\
lemma 3&                                      &theorem 3
\end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have known `\newlength` and `\setlength` method, but that is a bit annoyed.

EDIT
I have also known the `*` way, but I need to write a multiple lines text in the `\multirow` command, and then I have to assign the length to it. See [The \multirow command do not allow a multiple lines content inside itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233735/the-multirow-command-do-not-allow-a-multiple-lines-content-inside-itself)

Comment: `calc` changes how computations of widths for `minipage` or `\parbox` are made, but it doesn't the same for `multirow`. It should be this package's job to make it compatible with `calc`, not the other way around.

Comment: There is no need to try to use `\widthof`. Use of `*` is ok see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233967/4686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest another approach with the `makecell` package. The `makecell` command allows for line breaks inside cells, and I made a small patch to add the alignment (both vertical and horizontal) as an optional argument. Normally this optional argument is set in the preamble, but can be redefined anywhere.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\let\oldmakecell\makecell
\renewcommand{\makecell}[2][cc]{{\renewcommand\cellalign{#1}\oldmakecell{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r @{$\iff$}l}
    \makecell[r]{lemma 1\\ lemma 2 or 5\\ lemma 3}
      & \makecell[l]{theorem 1 \\ theorem 2 or 6\\ theorem 3 }
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vskip 0.5cm
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r @{$\iff$}l}
    \makecell[rt]{lemma 1\\ lemma 2 or 5\\ lemma 3}
      & \makecell[lb]{theorem 1 \\ theorem 2 or 6\\ theorem 3 }
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]